# How to show recent items first?

Tags: flutter, dart

I've a long list that holds some data, and whenever i add a new item to the list, the item added to the "end of the line".

How do i show the last added  item first?

Something like show recent items first

Comment: Add the item at 0 index, like `_yourList.insert(0, yourItem);`, call `setState()` after this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the item at 0 index, so use `List.insert` method.

```
setState(() {
  yourList.insert(0, yourItem);
});
```

---

And yes, there is difference between `List.add()` and `List.insert()`, the former adds the item to the end of the list and later allows you to add the item at some specified index.